# Move object to a parent object in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, object

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
   "id": 2,
   "title": "LA COPA",
   "parent_menu_id": nil
  },
  {
   "id": 3,
   "title": "CALENDARIO",
   "parent_menu_id": nil
  },
  {
   "id": 5,
   "title": "Torneo",
   "parent_menu_id": 2
  },
  {
   "id": 6,
   "title": "Nice",
   "parent_menu_id": 2
  }
]
```

This is the structure of a menu.

Each object is an menu item.

If the key "parent_menu_id" is nil, it means that the item is a parent menu.

If it has a value, is a children. I.E the third item means that item **id: 5 is child of item id:2.**

This is the desired output:

```
[
  {
   "id": 2,
   "title": "LA COPA",
   "active": true,
   "parent_menu_id": nil,
   "submenus":[
     {
       "id": 5,
       "title": "Torneo",
       "active": true,
       "parent_menu_id": 2
     },
     {
       "id": 6,
       "title": "Nice",
       "parent_menu_id": 2
     }
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": 3,
   "title": "CALENDARIO",
   "active": true,
   "parent_menu_id": nil
  }
]
```

I know the algorithm:

1. if pareny_menu_id is different than nill search the key id  == parent_menu_id
2. If submenu key is not present, create it.
3. Move the child item to the parent.
4. Then delete the child item from base location.

But I am not sure about the methods to use..

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: What language is that? Ruby has no notion of `null`.

Comment: @mudasobwa My, bad. You are right. I meant "nil"

Comment: @mudasobwa It is ruby :-)

Comment: Do you want Ruby or JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!ruby

require 'pp'

objects = [
  {
    "id"             => 2,
    "title"          => "LA COPA",
    "parent_menu_id" => nil
  },
  {
    "id"             => 3,
    "title"          => "CALENDARIO",
    "parent_menu_id" => nil
  },
  {
    "id"             => 5,
    "title"          => "Torneo",
    "parent_menu_id" => 2
  },
  {
    "id"             => 6,
    "title"          => "Nice",
    "parent_menu_id" => 2
  }
]

objects.collect! do |child|
  if not child["parent_menu_id"].nil? then
    parents = objects.select{|o| o["id"] == child["parent_menu_id"]}
    parents.each do |pr|
      pr["submenus"] ||= []
      pr["submenus"] << child
    end
  end
  child
end.select!{|o| o["parent_menu_id"].nil? }
pp objects
```

output:

```
[{"id"=>2,
  "title"=>"LA COPA",
  "parent_menu_id"=>nil,
  "submenus"=>
   [{"id"=>5, "title"=>"Torneo", "parent_menu_id"=>2},
    {"id"=>6, "title"=>"Nice", "parent_menu_id"=>2}]},
 {"id"=>3, "title"=>"CALENDARIO", "parent_menu_id"=>nil}]
```

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm on Ruby. But when I try to use it on Rails. I have the error: "can't write unknown attribute `submenus`".

Any chance you can migrate the code to rails?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Never mind! I figure it out using the as_json method. To transform all the ActiveRecord class to array and then process it. You are awesome!

Comment: Your changed the keys from symbols to strings and are missing the key-value pair `:active=> true` in your hash `{"id"=>5, "title"=>"Torneo", "parent_menu_id"=>2}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [
  {
   id: 2,
   title: "LA COPA",
   parent_menu_id: nil
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "CALENDARIO",
    parent_menu_id: nil
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "Torneo",
    parent_menu_id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    title: "Nice",
    parent_menu_id: 2
  }
]
```

```
parents, children = arr.partition { |g| g[:parent_menu_id].nil? }
  #= [[{:id=>2, :title=>"LA COPA", :parent_menu_id=>nil},
  #     {:id=>3, :title=>"CALENDARIO", :parent_menu_id=>nil}],
  #    [{:id=>5, :title=>"Torneo", :parent_menu_id=>2},
  #     {:id=>6, :title=>"Nice", :parent_menu_id=>2}]]

children.each do |child|
  parent_id = child[:parent_menu_id]
  parent = parents.find { |p| p[:id] == parent_id }
  if parent.key?(:submenus)
    parent[:submenus] << child
  else
    parent[:submenus] = [child.merge(active: true)]
  end
end

parents
  #=> [{:id=>2, :title=>"LA COPA", :parent_menu_id=>nil,
  #     :submenus=>[{:id=>5, :title=>"Torneo", :parent_menu_id=>2, :active=>true},
  #                 {:id=>6, :title=>"Nice", :parent_menu_id=>2}]},
  #    {:id=>3, :title=>"CALENDARIO", :parent_menu_id=>nil}]
```

Notes:

- `"id": 2` is redundant. Just use `id: 2`. You only need quotes when the symbol is comprised of more than one word.
- I assumed that the key value pair `active: true` is only present for the first element of the value (array) of `:submenus`.